# Difference between spring-boot:run and java -jar

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

What is the difference between running application using `mvn spring-boot:run` and `java -jar executable.jar`

Comment: One doesn't use Maven

Comment: First one will compile project before running the application.

Comment: Ok, sorry for duplicate topic I couldn't find it earlier